# YQL returns HTTP Status 500 - null

Tags: yql

YQL sometimes returns correct data and sometimes Status 500. On YQL FAQ is stated request limit 1,000 times per hour, what I'm definitely not exceeding. The same behaviour in my app or straight from browser.

Full reply from Yahoo is:

```
HTTP Status 500 - null
type Status report
message null
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

My yql url is:

[http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select Symbol, Open, PreviousClose, PercentChange, Volume, AskRealtime, DaysHigh, DaysLow from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ('AAPL', 'GOOG')&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20Symbol,%20Open,%20PreviousClose,%20PercentChange,%20Volume,%20AskRealtime,%20DaysHigh,%20DaysLow%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%27AAPL%27,%20%27GOOG%27%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys)

Comment: it looks like the problem is on the Yahoo YQL server side. Have tried the same yql query from their console and got the same result.